# Flot.js + user specified timezone for x-axis in rails application

Tags: timezone, ruby-on-rails-4, flot

I am using Flot charting library for displaying graphs. the User model has a 'timezone' field where he can specify his timezone. In the graph, the x-axis time needs to be displayed based on the user's timezone. The flot library takes browser's time as timezone but how do i set the user's timezone as the timezone to be considered for graph?

the code segment is as

```
xaxis:
  min: min_time
  max: max_time
  mode: "time"
  tickSize: [1, "hour"]
  #timezone: "browser" #takes browser's timezone if enabled
```

The Flot documentation http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-time/ specifies that user specific timezone can be loaded using timezoneJS https://github.com/mde/timezone-js

I set my system timezone to "Alaska" and specified "Kolkata" as user's timezone.

```
  timezone: "Asia/Kolkata" #specify the timezone to be considered
```

The browser picked up the system timezone even when above code was explicitly specified. It doesnt work. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you're looking for is actually [this one](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-time-zones/index.html).  If the example works for you, then I would figure out how your code (it would help if you could provide more of it, or a jsfiddle) differs.  Are you properly including timezonejs?  Any errors in the console?